# Reload Page on <input type="submit"> after some php code

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm displaying a Log File from my Raspberry Pi (Door closed / Door opened). 

I want to have the possibility to delete this Logfile with a Button.

And on the same button click the page should reload and display the empty Logfile.

I have following Code:

```
<form method="get" action="test.php">
    <input type="submit" value"test" name="test1">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['test1'])) {
    unlink('test.txt');
    touch('test.txt');
}
?>
```

This Code reloads the Page but doesn't display the empty log file. (But it deletes the Logfile and makes a new empty one).

What I want now is that the Page should reload after the PHP Code, so the empty Logfile is displayed instantly.
I have absolutely no idea what I can do?
Any hints?

Comment: To what purpose should the page reload? Submitting the form will cause a refresh (or redirect if test.php is another file)

Comment: I have a log file and the Button deletes this log file. This works fine but I want to display it instantly with a Page reload.

Comment: why do you want to reload? after they hit submit, the page is reloaded and everything in the HTML is fresh.

Comment: Ok it seems like the reload happens before the PHP code... but that's not what I want

Comment: The php code has run and finished before you see the form in your browser. And if you are going to delete files, you should use POST instead of GET.

Comment: I updated the Question a bit. I hope it gets more clear what I want and why i accepted the answer from Alfredo Delgado.

Comment: And now I use POST instead of GET and it works! Thanks @jeroen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['test1'])) {
    unlink('test.txt');
    touch('text.txt');
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: @jrenk but why? With what purpose?

Comment: I have a log File displayed. With the Button I want to delete it and also Display just an empty log file

Answer (score 0):

you can add php code first, so data will be up to date without reloading:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['test1'])) {
    unlink('test.txt');
    touch('text.txt');
}
?>
<form method="get" action="test.php">
    <input type="submit" value"test" name="test1">
</form>
```

Comment: if he has html output already, the `header` function wont work, instead then he could use the html `echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=redirect url here">';`

Comment: 1. A `header()` call will not work after outputting html to the browser and 2. the php code will run before the html hits the browser, wherever you place it.

Comment: right Dorvalla / jeroen, thanks for pointing this. I removed my "html first" solution. Usually, php code comes first, then the html output

Comment: It is certainly good practice to have your controller before you output html, but here there will be absolutely no difference between your code and the OP's code: After all the php has been parsed, the end-result (the form) will be sent to the browser.

Comment: @jeroen except as it turn out later code (that the OP alludes to but doesnt show) displays the contents of text.txt. This answer (running the php before any output) is therefore a better solution than the excepted answer. +1 from me